# Too many parameter values slowing down query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, ssms

I have a query that runs fairly fast under normal circumstances. But it is running very slow (at least 20 minutes in SSMS) due to how many values are in the filter.

Here's the generic version of it, and you can see that one part is filtering by over 8,000 values, making it run slow.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    column 
FROM 
    table_a a 
JOIN 
    table_b b ON (a.KEY = b.KEY)
WHERE 
    a.date BETWEEN @Start and @End
    AND b.ID IN (... over 8,000 values)
    AND b.place IN ( ... 20 values)
ORDER BY 
    a.column ASC
```

It's to the point where it's too slow to use in the production application.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or optimize the query?

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. And provide schemas. And indexes. And the actual execution plan. Try using <your favorite search engine> to search for `t sql in vs inner join`. You'll find articles like [this](https://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/) that may be of some help.

Comment: Why are you confused? You are doing 8K plus logical checks per row, of course it's going to be slow. The real question you should be asking is how to write a more optimal query, not why your suboptimal query is obviously slow. Can you expound upon why you might have an IN with 8k options?

Comment: Where did those 8000 values come from and why aren't they in a table in the database itself? Essentially, you are joining against a *third* table with 8K rows. Is `table_b.ID` covered by an index? Is it used? If it isn't, you force a seek for 8000 values. What is the execution plan for this?

Comment: Do you have indexes on the `a.Date`, `b.ID` and `b.place` columns? If you don't, you force an L x M x N search which obviously gets slower the more items you pass

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to put the filtering values in temporary table. Then use the table to apply filtering using `INNER JOIN` instead of `WHERE IN`. For example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FilterDataSource') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE #FilterDataSource;
END;

CREATE TABLE #FilterDataSource
(
    [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO #FilterDataSource ([ID])
-- you need to split values

SELECT DISTINCT column 
FROM table_a a 
INNER JOIN table_b b 
    ON (a.KEY = b.KEY)
INNER JOIN #FilterDataSource FS
    ON b.id = FS.ID
WHERE a.date BETWEEN @Start and @End
    AND b.place IN ( ... 20 values)
ORDER BY .column ASC;
```

Few important notes:

- we are using temporary table in order to allow parallel execution plans to be used
- if you have fast (for example CLR function) for spiting, you can join the function itself
- it is not good to use `IN` with many values, the SQL Server is not able to build always the execution plan which may lead to time outs/internal error - you can find more information [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/521943/the-query-processor-ran-out-of-internal-resources-and-could-not-produce-a-query-plan-with-where-in-and-several-thousand-values)

Comment: This will be drastically **slower**. Temporary tables do not affect parallel execution. The real problem is that the temporary table has no primary key or index, resulting in a full table scan for each ID. The `IN (...)` operation at least knows the statistics of the values. *This* temporary table though is just an unordered heap

Comment: Temporary tables are preferred over TVPs because they have statistics, while TVPs don't - they are treated as 1-row tables. The `IN()` operator also has statistics, which is why it's faster than a TVP

Comment: that's what *I* said. That is about **TVPs** vs temporary tables. The OP isn't using TVPs. You aren't using indexes, so there are no statistics. Your solution will be far worse because it has no indexes, no statistics *AND* will hit the disk. At least a TVP may not. Add a PRIMARY KEY if you want to get any performance gains

Comment: There is no question that if the table is wide and there are column value stored  `out of row`, using a right index is best. There is no information about the table structure, too, so talking is useless. I add this, because a week ago a dynamic query I debug was filtering using thousands values in `IN` clause  - if this is the case of the OP, this will help.

Comment: On the contrary, a missing primary key in the temporary table is guaranteed to lead to bad performance. Simply adding it will solve the problem. All that's needed is writing `[ID] INT PRIMARY KEY`. It won't even take extra space because a clustered index is essentially the table itself

Comment: The 8K+ values come from a multi select SSRS parameter. A temp table is no an option in this scenario for what I'm doing. I'm hoping the query can be re-written to work fast, perhaps using EXISTS or something else. Just not sure how

Answer (score 1):

To make a query fast, you need indexes.
You need a separate index for the following columns: a.KEY, b.KEY, a.date, b.ID, b.place.
As gotqn wrote before, if you put your 8000 items to a temp table, and inner join it, it will make the query even faster too, but without the index on the other part of the join it will be slow even then.