# Is there a way to join a parameter to a table?

Tags: t-sql, join, parameters, ssms

Not sure if this is possible based on what I've researched online. But just want to check to be sure.

If I have a parameter such as:

```
declare @Person nvarchar(4000)
set @Person = '1234567'
```

And I have a table called `[People]`, then can I join the two together?

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM [People] t1 JOIN @Person t2 ON (t1.ID = t2.ID)
```

Is such a thing possible and if so can someone please provide the syntax or an exmaple?

Comment: the parameter is a scalar value. why do you want to join it and what do you expect as result. also what is the number 1234567? is that the ID ?
 obviously you can declare a table variable and populate that and join with your table. This seems strange to me.

Comment: To the audience: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008157/exists-in-filter-returning-too-many-values) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989977/too-many-parameter-values-slowing-down-query) form the background without which this question makes little sense. Even so, ... . The `ssms` tag is, of course, spurious. And the database software is implied but not stated.

Comment: @HABO correctly labeled this post as being the third in a series by someone who is unwillingly to learn or read answers. Don't waste your time here, they aren't listening.

Answer (score 0):

Using this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.People (id int, peopleInfo nvarchar(4000));
INSERT dbo.People VALUES (123, 'joe'), (223, 'sally'), (323, 'Mary');
```

You can do this:

```
declare @Person nvarchar(4000) = '323'

SELECT t1.* 
FROM dbo.People t1 
JOIN (VALUES (@Person)) t2(id) ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

*But why not just do this?*

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM dbo.People t1 
WHERE t1.id = @Person;
```